# How to give high CPU to a Program in Windows 7

Tags: cpu-usage

I am running a computation intensive (solving a number theory problem) standalone java program from eclipse on my Windows 7 machine. No other application is running.

Now I started task manager and see javaw.exe taking only ~50%. Even after raising priority to high, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/44003/how-do-i-give-a-program-high-priority-for-memory-and-processor-speed), it still takes just 50%.

Is it possible to provide high CPU (say 90%) to this program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that your program is not designed with **multithreading** or **multi processor** based computation. Because of this the program is using, **fully**, one of the (im guessing) 2 cores of your machine.

Can you verify in the **task manager** tab "**Performance**" that one of the two boxes is showing **full usage** (100%) and one is **low**?

Comment: Note that with a 50% CPU use process on a dual core machine you probably won't see a 100%-0% split between cores, but more likely something like 85%-15% due to the process switching cores.

Answer (score 5):

If it is the only CPU intensive program running and it only gets ~50% CPU then there are two possible reasons:

1. It is waiting for something else. (Often disk access)
2. It is not multi threaded.
   With 50% this is most likely the case. Especially if you have a dual core CPU and the program is running flat out on one core, while the other core is idle.

Edit: You can test option 2 by starting **two** instances of the program. That will probably raise your CPU usage to 100%.